# How to use Spotlight to open a Chrome Bookmark?

Tags: spotlight, shortcuts-app

After using mac for a while now, I am often find that I am missing a few features and I am wondering if I am missing something.

Is there a way to open Chrome bookmarks from Spotlight? What I am looking for is a one stop tool to open my bookmarks from anywhere on my Mac.

Comment: I've removed your second question, the site works better with just one question per post (you can always ask additional questions). Also, at least for me, Spotlight shows the folder name when I enter it in the search field, a simple "Enter" opens the folder then.

Answer (score 0):

"Bookmarks and History" is an option for Spotlight search results, so if you type the name of a bookmark, it should show up.

However, I don't know whether the OS supports other browsers than Safari in this regard; or if it does, whether Spotlight would need to 'support it back'.

In short: I'd suggest that if Bookmarks is selected for search results, and you don't see bookmarks from Chrome, then the answer is "no".